# Calculating the sum of running total colum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting running total of particular column, but now I need to get the sum of running total column

```
id     somedate    somevalue  runningtotal   sumofrunning total
--     --------    ---------  ------------   ------------------ 
45     01/Jan/09   3          3                    138 
23     08/Jan/09   5          8                    138
12     02/Feb/09   0          8                    138   
77     14/Feb/09   7          15                   138 
39     20/Feb/09   34         49                   138  
33     02/Mar/09   6          55                   138
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select
    *,
    SUM(RunningTotal) OVER() SumOfRunningTotal
from
    YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result from your query in a temp table.

```
select ....
into # T
from ...
```

Calculate the sum value to a variable.

```
declare @sum bigint;

select sum(runningtotal)
from #T;
```

And finally do the query against the temp table.

```
select *, @sum as [sumofrunning total]
from #T
```

Another way would be to do a derived table of your existing query and use `sum() over()` in the main query.

```
select T.*, sum(T.runningtotal) over() as [sumofrunning total]
from (
     -- your query goes here
     select ...
     from ...
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (UGLY and SLOW), but seems working,

```
WITH somecte (id, somedate, somevalue, runningtotal, somegroupe )
AS
(
    SELECT 
      a.id,
      a.somedate,
      a.somevalue,
      -- Here goes your running total logic
      (SELECT SUM(b.somevalue)
                   FROM   sometable b
                   WHERE  b.somedate <= a.somedate) AS runningtotal,
      1 as somegroupe 

    FROM sometable a
  )


SELECT id, somedate, somevalue, runningtotal,
       (SELECT SUM(runningtotal)
        FROM somecte
        GROUP BY somegroupe) AS sumofrunningtotal

FROM somecte
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc84b/29)